# Grails Polling the server via ajax calls

Tags: ajax, grails, groovy, polling

I have a partial template that I want to intermittently poll the server (one of my controllers) and update its display with the result.

What is the appropriate way to do this with grails?

I have seen some articles saying there are specific grails tags for ajax calls, which would be nicer as it would allow clean direction to a controller/method, however, I've not seen anything in Grails to suggest that polling of a controller method could be done altogether.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's nothing built into Grails that will do the polling for you.  The most basic way is to simply use the setInterval() function in your JavaScript.  If you're using a JavaScript library then something might be available there that would make things easier on you.

As a side note, be careful when implementing polling.  If you're application isn't scaled correctly and you expect a lot of users, polling can bring your system down quickly.